# How to move or add a desired element as last element in a List depends its presence or not

Tags: python-3.x, list

I am calling a list via some function:

```
def chop_slice(main_list, slice_start, slice_end): 
    slice= main_list[slice_start:slice_end]
    
    if favourite_element not in slice:
        slice.insert(len(slice), favourite_element )
    return slice
```

Now, I would always want my `favourite_element` to be as the last element of the `slice` list. I could fulfil it when it was not present in the `slice` list, however when it was present, I could not make sure of this being as the last-element.

For example:

```
main_list = [1,2, 3, 4, 'favourite_element', 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
input: chop_slice(main_list, 0, 3)
output : [1,2,3, 'favourite_element']

input: chop_slice(main_list, 4, 7)
output: [5, 6, 7, 'favourite_element']
```

and so on..

Any suggestion, how to make sure of this?

Thanks,

Comment: Do you want it *moved* to the end, or *added* to the end (so it appears twice)?

Comment: Hi Scott, 1.) if its not present, it want to add it as last element 2.) if its present, then move it to the last place. So no doubling!!!

Comment: So the only piece of this you seem to be missing is how to *remove* something from a list (because once you remove it, you can then add it to the end).

Comment: @DanielHao, *favourite_element* is one of the element of the *main_list*. My requirement is to chop *main_list* into small lists, but have *favourite_elment* always as the last element of the output list.